# How to bend a path along an arc (or any shaped path)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path-effects

**TL:DR**

> How can I bend a shape along a path in illustrator

---

I've been wondering for a while how I can do this, when I saw this question, I got very excited.

[Inkscape: Bend a vector along a circular arc](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/103080/63979)

But the methods provided seem to be just for Inkscape.

---

I'm looking for a way to do this in Illustrator:

### Edit:

{This is just an example shape,I don't actually want it in this shape or curve - in Inkscape it's pertty simple, just bend on curve, I'm looking for a similar feature in illustrator}

I have (a group of) shapes and I want it curved along the <kbd>- - - - - -</kbd> line:

[image]

<sub>(Really just any path to my customization, just an example)</sub>

---

Or these shapes:

[image]

I want them to "warp" all the way around the circle (to make a complete star-ish)

This was the best I could get using *Object*→*Envelope Distort*→*Make with Warp* (Alt+Shift+Ctrl+W):

It is clearly not the desired effect, it needs to be dragged in further (and more consistently across the entire shape)

[image]

Note: This can *easily* be done with text: (just use the type on path tool)

[image]

> I'm looking for a way to do it with standard shapes/paths. I do not want to make a brush (unless it's my only option).

Why you ask?

If it's a brush, I have to make it beforehand manually (I can't just choose an item and bend it to X path - which I can do in Inkscape.) With a brush, the benefit would be to be able to have *full* control over the curves, but at a cost of extra time and effort, so sometimes I just want the computer to *do it's thing*

Comment: You say " I do not want to make a brush " - but in fact the Inkscape pattern along a path/bend from clipboard functions are somewhat analogous to brushes in Illustrator.  Indeed, since Inkscape lacks brushes as such, this is exactly how you would get something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Just save your shape as an art brush / pattern brush (depends on what are you trying to achieve)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Scatter Brush** with a triangle and apply this brush to a circle

[image: Scatter Brush]

Comment: That would work if the shape I wanted was an individual triangle. I'm looking for a way to do this with *arbitrary* shape(s) on *arbitrary* paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the **Star Tool** to draw the star... tap the up/down arrows while dragging to increase/decrease the number of points.

Then draw a circle, align them both, and use the **Pathfinder Panel** to subtract the circle from the star. Then recolor points as desired.

[image]

Comment: Yes that would work in said scenario (with those shapes), but say my curve was more like the last picture (with the text) and the shape I wanted bent was not triangles (but some other shape)

Comment: @WELZ Possibly this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/how-to-make-objects-follow-a-path-illustrator-like-on-the-las-vegas-sign -- it all kind of depends on the *actual* objects and distortion needed. There are a few methods but no "one-method-for-all" type of procedure.

Comment: I've edited the question to further explain what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm not really seeing much difference after the edit. I think the Envelope options are about as close as you're going to get with Illustrator. There's no other "live distort" feature of which I'm aware. And no "shape-on-a-path" features other than brushes. I understand what you're asking, I merely don't think it's possible via Illustrator.

Comment: I know you say it’s not what you want, but I’m pretty sure that brushes are the way forward for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The indesign answer is actually pretty good and worked well. All warping answers in illustrator distort the shape. In my case, I want to bend a logo inside a circle so that each letter follows a path, but not being distorted, and I can't seem to find an answer to that problem. It goes without saying that logo shouldn't be distorted in any situation. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to InDesign, it will do exactly what you're talking about. In InDesign, you can paste a vector as an inline graphic with text that follows a path of any shape. Because it is treated as text, you can also align however you like, spread with kerning, force justify, adjust baseline shift, etc. Once you're happy with the result, just copy and paste from InDesign into Illustrator.

[image]

Edit: Paste each shape individually, like individual letters of text. Groups will be treated a single objects and will align to the path, but will not conform to it.

Comment: Can I then copy the result back into illustrator as a vector path?

Comment: Unfortunately not. When you paste into Illustrator from InDesign, it will break the relationship to the path. However, you can save the InDesign file to make future edits easier. You can also save the vector as it's own AI file and link it as an inline graphic in InDesign. This will allow you to edit the source AI file and update in InDesign to instantly update that vector along the path.

Comment: It's not worth buying InDesign for, but if you already have InDesign, I think this is your most efficient way to accomplish your task.

Comment: I couldn't get it to bend, it would just place it straight [see gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfG1w.gif). Any ideas?

Comment: You have to paste one triangle at a time. It might be faster to paste one several times, then color them how you like.