# Is there a tool in Inkscape to "un-bend" a circular path to be straight?

Tags: inkscape, svg, patterns

I know there is a way to map an object with a rectangular area along a path in Inkscape (see [Inkscape: Bend a vector along a circular arc](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/103080/102930))

I would like to do the reverse: draw a path, and maybe give it a radius so that it can map a curved object back to a rectangle, so that I can remix the object into a different shape. I *think* I would know a gist of the algorithm involved, so I believe with some substantial work I could make my own tool to do it, but I'd rather find out that someone else has done it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making a curve that follows the unbend target, mirroring that curve horizontally, then applying that as a bend operation as in the link?